# C++ How to call a void function without errors?

Tags: c++

This is an assignment of mine that I picked to do but I am not sure how to fix the error message I am getting at `cout << contact.getInformation() << endl;`without changing the Void function to a different type or changing the main function (which I am trying to avoid). I think my lack of understanding is in how cout and void functions work together. I tried to remove the cout from the function but that did not work and the only way I could make the code run was when I replaced `cout << contact.getInformation() << endl;` with `contact.getInformation()` which I am trying to avoid. I just want the inside of the void function to print when I call `cout << contact.getInformation() << endl;`
Any help is welcome! Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Contact{

public:
    Contact(int id, string name, string telephone, int age)
    : _id{ id }, _name{ name }, _telephone{ telephone }, _age{ age } {}

    int id() { return _id; }
    string name() { return _name; }
    string telephone() { return _telephone; }
    int age() { return _age; }

    void getInformation() {
        cout << "ID: " + to_string(_id) + "\n" +
        "NAME: " + _name + "\n" +
        "TEL: " + _telephone + "\n" +
        "AGE: " + to_string(_age) + "\n";
    }
private:
    int _id;
    string _name;
    string _telephone;
    int _age;

};

int main() {
    Contact contact{1, "Michael", "555-555-5555", 15};
    cout << contact.getInformation() << endl;
}.
```

EDIT: Thanks all! I see now that it is impossible to do with those restrictions.

Comment: Don't put it inside `cout`, just call it. Or have it return a `std::string` instead of printing it.

Comment: change `void getInformation()` to `std::string getInformation()`. Instead of doing the print, make it return the stuff that it was going to print. Or perhaps you would have no qualms about just calling `contact.getInformation();` if you rename the function `printInformation`, as that better describes what it is doing.

Comment: Also, if you don't want to change neither the `main` nor the `getInformation` method, what else do you think you can change to avoid a problem caused by them?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=vs-2017

Comment: The only way to make it right is to change one of the two things that make it wrong.

Comment: The error message is Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'void') @BogdanDoicin

Comment: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Contact& contact)` would adding something like this work @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: @Joe.corn your last comment is unreadable, don't post code longer than one line in comments but instead [edit]  your question and put all complementary information _there_

Comment: sorry about that @Jabberwocky I will do that in future edits

Comment: @Joe.corn no need to edit your question and add a "thank you". Rather upvote the answers you think are useful and accept the answer you think is the best one.

Answer (score 6):

The code you've provided have many issues. You can avoid them if you read some good C++ book, my advice is Scott Meyers  Effective C++: 55 Specific Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs.

1. don't use using directive unless really necessary. In most cases for std namespace - it is not.
2. Pass function arguments of non primitive type by reference/const reference rather by value or pointer
3. Understand const keyword and it usage
4. Understand constructor static initialization bocks
5. Understand c++ streams

This is how you code should looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Contact {

public:
    Contact(int id,const std::string& name,const std::string& telephone, int age):
        _id( id ),
        _name( name ),
        _telephone( telephone ),
        _age( age )
    {}

    int id() const {
        return _id;
    }
    std::string name() const {
        return _name;
    }
    std::string telephone() const {
        return _telephone;
    }
    int age() const {
        return _age;
    }


private:
    int _id;
    std::string _name;
    std::string _telephone;
    int _age;

};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& to,const Contact& c)
{
    to << "ID: " << c.id() << '\n';
    to << "NAME: " << c.name() << '\n';
    to << "TEL: " << c.telephone() << '\n';
    to << "AGE: " << c.age() << '\n';
    to.flush();
    return to;
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    Contact contact = {1, "Michael", "555-555-5555", 15};
    std::cout << contact << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking is not possible. The two conditions you have set (i.e. 1. Do not change the void function to another type, and 2. Do not alter the main method) make it impossible to change your code in some other way so as for the main function to produce the intended outcome.

You can *either* alter your void function to one that returns something 'printable', e.g. a string, *or* you can keep your void function printing to cout directly, but then change the main function to call this on its own, outside the context of a `cout <<` construct.

(Or, preferably, as has also been pointed in the comments, instead of void, overload the `<<` operator to make cout work with your specific object type)

Answer (score 4):

The name `getInformation` suggests it should, well, *get* the information and not *print* it.

Therefore you probably want this:

```
  string getInformation() {
    return  "ID: " + to_string(_id) + "\n" +
      "NAME: " + _name + "\n" +
      "TEL: " + _telephone + "\n" +
      "AGE: " + to_string(_age) + "\n";
  }
```

Instead of this:

```
  void getInformation() {
    cout << "ID: " + to_string(_id) + "\n" +
      "NAME: " + _name + "\n" +
      "TEL: " + _telephone + "\n" +
      "AGE: " + to_string(_age) + "\n";
  }
```

Not changing `main` nor `getInformation` is not possible.

Comment: you are right, but this does not answer the actual question, and in fact is exactly what OP asked you should not suggest.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou what the OP is asking is not possible.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think that is what the answer to this question should explain. (+1)